# Avoid select before update in Hibernate/Repository save - Java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, repository, persistence

I already do a select in the database (oracle) before starting the process to have the data recovered.

Then I see if it exists and assemble the objects according to the returned id.

When doing the repository.save() of my list, I'm doing a select before each update and I don't want that because it's taking too long to execute, because I already guaranteed initially with the select that the data is in the database.

Is it possible for me to add some configuration that never selects before the update?

I already tried using the @SelectBeforeUpdate(false) notation inside my entities, but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You need to avoid making a call to repository.save() then. You can use JPA EnityManager.

```
list.forEach(item -> entityManager.persist(item));
```

Comment: It doesn't solve it, because I get the exception "detached entity passed to persist hibernate".
If you try the .merge() of success, but continue doing the select.

Comment: you need to make select under transactional context. otherwise JPA will always fetch the state from db.

Comment: I changed it to do everything inside a method annotated with @Transactional, but it didn't work.

I believe it doesn't work because the select I do is in a database view that already has several unions with several tables to make it easier. Then with this view I assemble my list with the id filled in.

Comment: While you may be in a context, it seems like your query isn't returning managed entities, so JPA doesn't know about them. If you can, rework your query so it goes through JPA constructs and returns entities it manages within the context and it then won't have to requery for the data to determine they exist (and the deltas).